# Product name and sku is same for configurable product in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I used **magento 1.9.2.1**. When i create **configurable product** with ***csv upload*** and give `_super_products_sku` , it will automatically set its name too.

Is there any other way to set its name ?

I google it but did not find any information.

Comment: name is required attribute for product. without product name it is not import product